# ¿Como puedo crear un script batch para crear copias de seguridad en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, script, batch

Estoy intentado crear un archivo .bat para crear backup's de la base de datos pero nada me funciona, por ahora este es mi código. Crea la carpeta y todo correcto, hasta la hora de hacer el login. El mensaje que me muestra en pantalla es un timeout pero no entiendo el por que si tiene usuario y contraseña correctos.

intente cambiar el ServerName por "localhost\SQLEXPRESS pero tampoco funciona así, de lo contrario de esta forma simplemente rompe al ejecutar el cmd.

```
@echo off

SET FirstDir=%~d0

IF "%~d0"=="E:" SET "curr_dir=%~d0" 

IF NOT "%~d0"=="E:" SET curr_dir=%cd%

CD /D E:\


IF EXIST TestDB_Data_Backup ( 
cd TestDB_Data_Backup
) ELSE ( 
mkdir TestDB_Data_Backup
cd TestDB_Data_Backup
)

SET server=SQLEXPRESS

SET dataBase=pruebaDB

SET user=root

SET password=root

SET day=%date:~7,2%

SET month=%date:~4,2%

SET year=%date:~10,4%

SET myDateFormat=%day%-%month%-%year%

SET myDateFormat=%myDateFormat: =%

SET hour=%time:~0,2%

SET minute=%time:~3,2%

SET sec=%time:~6,2% 

SET myTimeFormat=%hour%-%minute%-%sec%

SET myTimeFormat=%myTimeFormat: =%
   
ECHO Batch file is ready to backup the %dataBase% database 

PAUSE

SET pathName=E:\TestDB_Data_Backup\

SET fullName=TestDB-Full Database Backup 

GOTO BeginBackupSQLCommandInBatchFile
        This code is used to call SQL commands in batch file
        -S (server name)
        -U (user name)
        -P (password)
        -d (database name)
        -Q (call query)
        In here the system write the database backup at "E:\TestDB_Data_Backup\TestDB_[date]_[time].bak" 
        This backup file is made by SQL Script which it is write at the batch file
:BeginBackupSQLCommandInBatchFile

sqlcmd -S %server% -U %user% -P %password% -d %dataBase% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE %dataBase% TO  DISK = '%pathName%%dataBase%_%myDateFormat%_%myTimeFormat%.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'%fullName%', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;"

ECHO Backup File is Created.....

CHDIR /D %FirstDir%

PAUSE

EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui veo dos cosas,

Primero, verifica realmente que el nombre del servidor sea el correcto en SQLEXPRESS el cual puedes sustituir por "localhost" o ".\SQLEXPRESS" recuerda que le coloco el "." como abreviatura si utilizas una instancia local ("localhost\SQLEXPRESS").

```
SET server=localhost
```

o

```
SET server=.\SQLEXPRESS
```

Segundo, Recuerda que a veces las conexiones pueden llevar más tiempo de lo esperado asi que deberias agregar por lo menos 30 segundos en la opcion de tiempo de espera extendido, escribiendo "-l 30" en tu sentencia sqlcmd

...asi:

```
sqlcmd -S %server% -U %user% -P %password% -d %dataBase% -l 30 -Q "BACKUP DATABASE %dataBase% TO  DISK = '%pathName%%dataBase%_%myDateFormat%_%myTimeFormat%.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'%fullName%', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;"
```

RECOMENDACION: Si estas ejecutando este script desde la misma máquina donde se encuentra la base de datos, considera utilizar la autenticación integrada de windows en lugar de autenticación SQL, esto lo puedes hacer quitando las líneas relacionadas con usuario y clave  simplemente utilizando "-E" en el comando sqlcmd.

quedando asi:

```
sqlcmd -S %server% -d %dataBase% -E -l 30 -Q "BACKUP DATABASE %dataBase% TO  DISK = '%pathName%%dataBase%_%myDateFormat%_%myTimeFormat%.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'%fullName%', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;"
```